# Unable to create nullable foreign key using efcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am trying to create a code-first class where there may or may not exist a foreign key relation. My class is

```
public class InventoryReturn
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  [Required]
  public int InventoryReturnID { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int ReturnType { get; set; }

  public int SerialNumber;

  public int? InventoryID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("InventoryID")]
  public virtual Inventory Inventory { get; set; }

}
```

Here I have specified InventoryID as optional but when I try to add a row wihtout specifying it, I get an error

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80084005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I tried generating the mysql migration script for this using **dotnet ef migrations script** , and found the below script generated

```
CREATE TABLE `InventoryReturns` (
`InventoryReturnID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ReturnType` int NOT NULL,
`InventoryID` int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `PK_InventoryReturns` PRIMARY KEY (`InventoryReturnID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_InventoryReturns_Inventories_InventoryID` FOREIGN KEY (`InventoryID`) REFERENCES `Inventories` (`InventoryID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
```

Here it shows InventoryID NOT NULL.

Why is this happening, I am using  **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**

Comment: Since EF generated a `NOT NULL` column for `InventoryID ` you probably have some mapping code that configures it as required.

Comment: @GertArnold I am using automapper, but there are none with "required"

Comment: What does `Inventory` look like? (The class). And I mean EF mapping code like in `OnModelCreating`.

Answer (score 4):

Answer was you must have optional on navigation property too. So in model I changed to

```
[ForeignKey("InventoryID")]
public virtual Inventory? Inventory { get; set; }
```

and issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need this

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<InventoryReturn>()
    .HasOptional<Inventory>(u => u.Inventory)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

[source1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d3ea1cd-a9f5-4b3e-8fd6-314a78b1e170/change-foreign-key-to-nullable-using-code-first?forum=aspadoentitylinq#5554732)
[source2](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/23086821/how-to-allow-null-values-on-foreign-keys-using-ef-)

Comment: it shows syntax error : 'EntityTypeBuilder<InventoryReturn>' does not contain a definition for 'HasOptional'

Comment: try this  : .HasOne<Inventory>(u => u.Inventory)